# msg 102,level 15,state 1,line 9 Incorrect syntax near '('-

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am working on a cross tab query in SQL Server 2008. Everything appear fine apart from this error I am getting.

Here is my code:

```
select * from 
    (select ITEM_CODE,NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY,RAW_MATERIAL_CODE,DATE_ID  from dbo.ODST_PRODUCTION_TRANS 
    ) n
    pivot
    (sum(NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY) for datename(month,DATE_ID) In ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June])) as pvt
where RAW_MATERIAL_CODE = 'X' and DATE_ID between '01-Jan-11' and '30-Jun-11'.
```

The problem is where the `datename(month,date_id)` but I can't figure it out. Can anyone give me a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the FOR part of a pivot can be a calculated value at the time of pivot and it must be in your result set.

```
select * from 
    (select ITEM_CODE,NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY,RAW_MATERIAL_CODE,DATE_ID,datename(month,DATE_ID) as dn  from dbo.ODST_PRODUCTION_TRANS 
    ) n
    pivot
    (sum(NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY) for dn In ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June])) as pvt
where RAW_MATERIAL_CODE = 'X' and DATE_ID between '01-Jan-11' and '30-Jun-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from 
    (select ITEM_CODE,NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY,RAW_MATERIAL_CODE,DATE_ID, datename(month,DATE_ID) as Month from dbo.ODST_PRODUCTION_TRANS 
    ) n
    pivot
        (
            sum(NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY) 
            for Month 
            In ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June])
        ) as pvt
where RAW_MATERIAL_CODE = 'X' and DATE_ID between '01-Jan-11' and '30-Jun-11'
```

I don't think the pivot likes the datename expression, so I've moved it into the query.

Comment: you are right,it should have been in the the query.thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
select * from         
        (select ITEM_CODE,NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY,RAW_MATERIAL_CODE,DATE_ID,datename(month,[DATE_ID]) as dtt 
from dbo.ODST_PRODUCTION_TRANS) as n
       pivot

            (
        sum(NET_PRODUCTION_QUANTITY) 
        for [dtt] IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June])) as pvt 
        where RAW_MATERIAL_CODE = 'X' and DATE_ID between '01-Jan-11' and '30-Jun-11'
```